# Giving preferences to classpaths in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, reflection

There are several classpath for a application (some of them are added during runtime). I want to read a file which present in two different locations. Depending upon the situation I have to load a particular file. So, I am thinking of giving preference to the classpaths. But, I don't know how it can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read any file from the classpath using the classloader

```
ExampleClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/file/inside/class.path");
```

If the resource exists multiple times inside the classloader, the first encountered resource will be taken.

Comment: Yes, that's what the OP clearly already knows. The question is: how to force that a particular one gets preference should there be a classpath conflict. Your answer contains correct information but in no way answers the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

The ClassLoader object allows you to get a [list of all resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources%28java.lang.String%29) mapped to the same resource path

```
  Enumeration<URL> resources = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("/path/to/file/inside/class.path");
```

the url should enable you to find out from which jar the file comes from

note that it would be more robust to use the java services feature: implement an interface to load resources which returns also a priority

public interface Loader {
      InputStream getResource(String name);
      int priority();
   }

then load the services loading resources using the [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class, sort them by the priority number returned by the implementation and then run getResource on them in order until the resource is found.